# How to process some HTML-tags (not all) from strings?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS.

I am facing an problem with AngularJS and problem is that, I received a string like from server and assigned it to model `"<p>Hello<\/p><p>to all!<\/p>"`. So, the result I can see on the page is `<p>Hello</p><p>to all!</p>`. I want `<p>`-tags be applied like this:

```
<p>Hello</p><p>to all!</p>
```

How can I get this using Angular? I also need to use some other tags like `<b>`,`<ul>` and others. But dangerous tags like `<script>` and `<style>` should be rejected. Also markup tags such as `<table>`, `<div>` should be avoided.

And this is my markup:

```
    <div flex layout="row">
        {{instance.description}}
    </div>
```

Comment: How can you bing `ngModel` to a non-input tag in the first place?

Comment: @Alon Eitan, not `ngModel`. I edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: Read about the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) along with [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) for this kind of use cases.

A perfect tutorial of how to use these is [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx), Do spend some time checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive

```
<div flex layout="row" ng-bind-html="instance.description">
</div>
```

You need to have [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module in your application to protect against malicious code